# sp_get_query_template doesn't work with ODBC timestamp

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp, odbc, plan-guides

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME FROM LICENSE WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = 'T' AND ALLOCATED = 'T' UNION ALL SELECT USER_NAME FROM LICENSE WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = 'T' AND ALLOCATED = 'F' AND "TIME" >= {ts '2023-10-02 08:09:12'})AS TEMP_ALIAS
```

When i try to create a plan guide with sp_get_query_template the plan guide doesn't work and i think that the cause is the ODBC timestamp value.

```sql
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max);  
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max);  
EXEC sp_get_query_template   
    N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME FROM LICENSE WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = ''T'' AND ALLOCATED = ''T'' UNION ALL SELECT USER_NAME FROM LICENSE WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = ''T'' AND ALLOCATED = ''F'' AND "TIME" >= {ts ''2023-10-02 08:09:12''})AS TEMP_ALIAS',  
    @stmt OUTPUT,   
    @params OUTPUT;  

    select @stmt
    select @params

EXEC sp_create_plan_guide   
    N'UsersCountTable',   
    @stmt,   
    N'TEMPLATE',   
    NULL,   
    @params,   
    N'OPTION(PARAMETERIZATION FORCED)';
```

I've tried also specifing timestamp parameter as:
VARCHAR(), DATEATIME, SMALLDATETIME, DATETIME2
with no success.

Does anybody knows how to make it works?